# How to createOrReplaceTempView in Delta Lake?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I want to use Delta Lake tables in my Hive Metastore on Azure Data Lake Gen2 as basis for my company's lakehouse.

Previously, I used "regular" hive catalog tables. I would load data from parquet into a spark dataframe, and create a temp table using `df.CreateOrReplaceTempView("TableName")`, so I could use Spark SQL or %%sql magic to do ETL. After doing this, I can use `spark.sql` or `%%sql` on the TableName. When I was done, I would `write` my tables to the hive metastore.

However, what If I don't want to perform this saveAsTable operation, and write to my Data Lake? What would be the best way to perform ETL with SQL?

I know I can persist Delta Tables in the Hive Metastore through a multitude of ways, for instance by creating a Managed catalog table through `df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("LakeHouseDB.TableName")`

I also know that I can create a DeltaTable object through the `DeltaTable(spark, table_path_data_lake)`, but then I can only use the Python API and not sql.

Does there exist some equivalent of `CreateOrReplaceTempView()`, or is there a better way to achieve ETL with SQL without 'writing' to the data lake first?

Comment: Did you try to create a temp view over a Delta table? Are you perhaps trying to achieve "zero-write Spark SQL"?

Comment: I did try to, yes. But I get an error: 'AttributeError: 'DeltaTable' object has no attribute 'createOrReplaceTempView'. I think I am trying to achieve "zero-write Spark SQL", as I believe that the most efficient way to do ETL is to load data into Spark memory once, do transformations, and then write to Hive Metastore. But since Hive Metastore is basically just a metadata layer upon files in the Delta Lake, I'm not completely sure If that is the way to go. I could also use the DeltaTable API to do Updates Deletes etc. but I like using SQL for this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I'm successfully doing that, in notebooks within Azure Synapse Analytics.  In a `%%pyspark` cell, I can `df.createOrReplaceTempView("ViewName")` and in a `%%sql` cell, I can then `create table LakeHouseDB.TableName  USING DELTA  as select <columnslist> from ViewName`  ((P.S. at least in ASA, the methodname "createOrReplaceTempView" is case-sensitive:  has to begin with lower-case "c".))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, what If I don't want to perform this saveAsTable operation, and write to my Data Lake? What would be the best way to perform ETL with SQL?

Not possible with Delta Lake since it relies heavily on a transaction log (`_delta_log`) under the data directory of a delta table.